# Convert a decimal number to a fraction AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, decimal, fractions, rational-number

I'm trying to get to convert the decimals to a fraction so for example, I had written something such as `var _pow:int = Math.pow(base,i)` and if `i` turned out to be a negative number it would give out a decimal (example: 3 ^ -2) and I'm currently stuck trying to find a way to turn _pow into a franction (so _pow out of a 100) so I tried to do `var _pow:int = Math.pow(base,i) * 100` which should stop it from being a decimal but it's not showing in the dynamic text, and this only happens if `i` is negative

```
package{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class name_ extends MovieClip{

        public function _name_(){
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, input)

            base.restrict = "0-9\\.\\-";
            pow.restrict = "0-9\\.\\-";
            answer.multiline = true; 

        }

        private function input(event:MouseEvent):void{
            var pow  = pow.text;
            var base = base.text;
            var answerText:String = "";

            if(pow > 0){
                for(var i = 1; i <= pow; i++){
                     _pow = Math.pow(base,i);
                    answerText += ("\n" + base + " exposant(power) " + i + " = "+ _pow ); 
                    answer.text = answerText; 
                    }

            }else{
                for(i = 1; i <= pow; i++){
                    var _pow:int = Math.pow(base,i) * 100           
                    answerText += ("\n" + base + " exposant(power) " + i + " = "+ _pow ); 
                    answer.text = answerText; //Dynamic text
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A stupid question: your code allows `pow` to be fractal. What should it return if you've got `3.5` for base and `-1.33` for pow?

Comment: One way I would do it is to convert a decimal to a fraction based on the number of decimal places used and then determining the greatest common factor of the two numbers. Like 0.2 -> 2/10 -> 1/5... 0.25 -> 25/100 -> 1/4... 0.275 -> 275/1000 -> 11/40. At face value it doesn't seem super difficult, but I don't know how hard it is to find greatest common factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using an "if" statement?  Something like if(i <= 0){*code*}.

You can also try using the Math.floor(*number to be rounded down*); or Math.ceiling(*number to be rounded up*)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work(the if statement), I also tried the part where I try out Math.ceil (it doesn't seem to work either)

`for(i = 1; i <= pow; i++){
                    var _pow:int = Math.ceiling( Math.pow(base,i)) * 100           
                    answerText += ("\n" + base + " exposant(power) " + i + " = "+ _pow ); 
                    answer.text = answerText; //Dynamic text
`
but it still gives out the same result to, even with the if statement, it doesn't show up in the dynamic text, only when `_pow` is positive it shows

Comment: Ok so I just reread your code and the declaration of "_pow" is "pow" that is in conflict with the function of Math.pow(base, i).  Seems like you have a lot of syntax errors as well, but those should not let the program compile.
These two lines should have pow = _pow, and also include a variable type.
            var pow  = pow.text;
            var base = base.text;

This line you don't need to declare the variable cause you already have in that function.
            var _pow:int = Math.pow(base,i) * 100  

You probably don't need the * 100 unless it's restricted to 2 decimal places.

Comment: Oh crap, it worked, I really appreciate what you did for me man, I really do :), thank you for helping me out, with my problem